# FB SDK Stuck on 3.24 with CocoaPods

Tags: swift, cocoapods, xcode7

Heyo,

I've been happily using Cocoapods with Xcode for a while now, but i just realized a rather annoying problem.

My facebook SDK isn't getting updated pas v3.24!

My podfile is up to date,

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseUI'
pod 'ParseCrashReporting'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtils'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'"
```

but whenever I update it's the same,

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Bolts (1.3.0)
Using FBSDKCoreKit (4.6.0)
Using FBSDKLoginKit (4.6.0)
Using Facebook-iOS-SDK (3.24.0)
Using FontAwesome.swift (0.5.0)
Using GoogleMaps (1.10.3)
Using Parse (1.8.5)
Using ParseCrashReporting (1.8.5)
Using ParseFacebookUtils (1.8.5)
Using ParseUI (1.1.6)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
```

I am now thinking this is causing problems with my attempted integration with swift 2.0 on Xcode7.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!!

Comment: It seems that this SDK is obsoleted, you have to add FBSDKCoreKit : https://cocoapods.org/pods/Facebook-iOS-SDK

Comment: Thanks, but I already am, and it's still not downloading the right SDK. Check out my podfile.

Comment: My Bad, I used your Podfile, it installs Facebook-iOS-SDK (3.24.0) for me too

Comment: Please remove that extra quotes at the end of the Podfile

Answer (score 1):

The source of Facebook-iOS-SDK is [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/ParseFacebookUtils/1.8.5/ParseFacebookUtils.podspec.json#L54-L56). The newest version of ParseFacebookUtils is stuck at [1.8.5](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs/ParseFacebookUtils) in [CocoaPods Specs repo](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs). So, the version downloaded is 3.24.0.

Also Facebook-iOS-SDK on CocoaPods is stuck at [4.1.0](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs/Facebook-iOS-SDK) even though [this](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tags) shows that 4.6.0 has been released. The CocoaPods Spec repo lags behind the most recent changes (as we can see that 4.6.0 was released just 20 days before today).

The workaround is to fork the Specs repo yourself on github and update the tag numbers. Then you can point your Podfile to your fork on github (Check the first line of your Podfile)

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-install pod if you don't find the solution:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

then

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

then do an pod update

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize that the syntax changed, and the rest of the world had moved on to `ParseFacebookUtilsV4`, and it turns out that my CocoaPods saw that the older `ParseFacebookUtils` was still using pieces from the `Facebook-IOS-SDK`.

Changing to `ParseFacebookUtilsV4` fixed everything!